# Laravel - Please how can I make a form field editable by a user when it has no value inside, but read-only when it has value on it

Tags: php, html, laravel, forms, laravel-blade

I need a help on a project I am working on using Laravel.
I am working on user profile page.

During user registration on a page, a user can choose to provide username or skip it.
I have no problem with that.
But I want on the user profile page, if the user wants to edit their details.
I want the user to be able to edit and add his/her username in the profile user name for field, if only they doesn't have username already.
But if the user has a username already, then, they can't change/edit their username.
If they have username already, then on the user profile page, they username field should be read-only while displaying their username to them without being able to edit/change the username again from their end.
This is my form username field code sample.
A help will really be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="username">@lang('Username')</label>
<input type="text"
       class="form-control input-solid"
       id="username"
       placeholder="(@lang('Enter username'))"
       name="username"
       value="{{ $edit ? $user->username : '' }}">
```

Comment: Add a `disabled` (or `readonly`) attribute to the input if the username is set

Comment: you can use disabled attribute in a HTML input, for more info https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_disabled.asp and with Laravel use the if staments https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/blade#if-statements fot show disabled option or editable option

Comment: Something like `<input {{ $user->username ? 'readonly' : '' }}>`? Keep in mind that they can still edit that by right-clicking and removing the `readonly` property. You will probably need some backend validation/logic to prevent updating that if it's already set too.

Comment: Better yet, if the username is already set, don't show an `<input>` but only display the username

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [Laravel blade if statement](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#if-statements) directive to conditionally render the input field like this:

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="username">@lang('Username')</label>
    @if($user->username ?? false)
    <input type="text"
           class="form-control input-solid"
           id="username"
           placeholder="(@lang('Enter username'))"
           name="noname"
           value="{{ $user->username }}" disabled>
    @else
    <input type="text"
           class="form-control input-solid"
           id="username"
           placeholder="(@lang('Enter username'))"
           name="username"
           value="{{ $edit ? $user->username : '' }}">
    @endif
</div>
```

I'm using `disabled` here because apart from making the field read-only it also prevents the field from being submitted. Use `readonly="readonly"` if you still want the read-only field to be submitted. Also, I changed the name of the read-only field so that even if it is edited by a hacker on the client and submitted, your server PHP script simply ignores it without errors (I'm assuming you don't want it submitted). If you still want to submit it, keep the correct name.

I'll also suggest that on your server side controller, you conditionally validate the username field for extra protection. E.g.

```php
function update(Request $request, User $user) 
{
    if($user->username ?? false) {
        // ignore username field, validate other user input fields and update profile
    } else {
        // validate username field with other fields and update profile
    }
}
```

**CAUTION**

Any one with html knowledge can edit your html on a client browser and submit it. Chances are that a hacker will attempt this after highjacking another user session. Use [Laravel csrf](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/csrf) protection always to prevent this.

Comment: @DidyouKnow really good to know I was of help to you. Pls, you can also give an upvote thanks

Answer (score 0):

For allowing the users who don't have username just for the UI:

```js
document.getElementById("editUserName").addEventListener("click", enableUserNameEditing);

function enableUserNameEditing(){
  document.getElementById("username").disabled = false;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
<label for="username">username</label>
<input type="text"
       class="form-control input-solid"
       id="username"
       placeholder="user name"
       name="username"
       value="john doe"
       disabled
       >
<button id='editUserName'>edit</button>
</div>
```

**You should add validation server sided if user has already username don't update.**

on the edit buttons and the JS you can add checks

```
$show_edit = empty($user->username) ? true : false;
```

now you can use this `$show_edit` variable to control the permissions for user to see show `username` field should behave:

```
<input type="text"
   class="form-control input-solid"
   id="username"
   placeholder="(@lang('Enter username'))"
   name="username"
   value="{{ $edit ? $user->username : '' }}"
   {{ $show_edit === false ? "disabled" : "" }}>

@if($show_edit)
   <button id='editUserName'>edit</button>
@endif
```

Comment: That would still allow the user to edit the username when it's already set though

Comment: Try the snippet I added for you, Edit button should allow all users to fill the username once they press edit button, we can only help you with the code the rest depends on the UX flow

Comment: No need to help me, I'm not OP. ;) First comment still stands valid, if a username is set, this would still allow a user to edit it - not what OP wants

Comment: ah my bad then thanks for pointing I will edit my answer